# How to take particular number for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table sport statistic table:

[image]

I would like 10 last records from the table for each team and then analyze and aggregate them.

Totally, I have 12 records for each team. But I want to analyze 10 only. I have the following SQL query

```
select
       guest_team_id,
       home_team_id,
       count(drawn)          drawn_count,
       count(home_team_lost) home_team_lost_count,
       count(home_team_won)  home_team_won_count,
       count(*) total
from statistic_records
group by home_team_id, guest_team_id;
```

with the following result
[image]

and have no idea how to limit records quantity for each team.

Any ideas?

Comment: wouldn't simple where condition do this?

Comment: I think no((
How exactly could I say with the help of where: "hey postgre! For each team, take only 10 records".

Comment: Please review the [`greatest-n-per-group`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag. Hint: use window functions. Happy searching and coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Analytical function to achieve that -

```
SELECT guest_team_id,
       home_team_id,
       count(drawn)          drawn_count,
       count(home_team_lost) home_team_lost_count,
       count(home_team_won)  home_team_won_count,
       count(*) total
from (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY home_team_id ORDER BY id) rn
        FROM statistic_records)
WHERE rn <= 10
group by home_team_id, guest_team_id;
```